# How do I deinterlace an image in Python?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Let's assume the image is stored as a png file and I need to drop every odd line and resize the result horizontally to 50% in order to keep the aspect ratio.

The result must have 50% of the resolution of the original image.

It will not be enough to recommend an existing image library, like PIL, I would like to see some working code.

**UPDATE** - Even if the question received a correct answer, I want to warn others that PIL is not in a great shape, the project website was not updated in months, there is no link to a bug traker and the list activity is quite low. I was surprised to discover that a simple BMP file saved with Paint was not loaded by PIL.

Comment: Let me be clear - you're asking how to use PIL to do this? Or you're asking how to do it without PIL?

Comment: Looks like PIL's `im.transform` could be useful. If not, there's `im.resize`, and you can do pixel-level operations for the rest. You have 5100 rep and a gold badge, so I assume you can take it from there.

Comment: PIL is ok, I updated the question. I was looking for some working code, for documenting the procedure for others. I'm sure I can write the code myself but I'm bored to answer my own questions.

Comment: you're asking this question to document this procedure for other people?

Comment: It looks like no one happens to have coded the exact thing you're looking for, so it would probably be faster to just code it up yourself at this point.

Comment: This is my first experience with PIL and i wasn't able to find what I was looking for in the documentation.

Comment: The direct dirty way would be to create a new pil image 1/2 the size, double nested for loop, and the call to putpixel http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it essential to keep every even line (in fact, define "even" - are you counting from `1` or `0` as the first row of the image?)

If you don't mind which rows are dropped, use PIL:

```
from PIL import Image
img=Image.open("file.png")
size=list(img.size)
size[0] /= 2
size[1] /= 2
downsized=img.resize(size, Image.NEAREST) # NEAREST drops the lines
downsized.save("file_small.png")
```

Comment: This works because the default filter for `resize` is `NEAREST`, which throws away every other pixel. +1 for a really simple solution.

Comment: Thanks Mark - I should've mentioned my use of the `NEAREST` default.

Answer (score 1):

I recently wanted to deinterlace some stereo images, extracting the images for the left and right eye. For that I wrote:

```
from PIL import Image

def deinterlace_file(input_file, output_format_str, row_names=('Left', 'Right')):
    print("Deinterlacing {}".format(input_file))
    source = Image.open(input_file)
    source.load()
    dim = source.size

    scaled_size1 = (math.floor(dim[0]), math.floor(dim[1]/2) + 1)
    scaled_size2 = (math.floor(dim[0]/2), math.floor(dim[1]/2) + 1)

    top = Image.new(source.mode, scaled_size1)
    top_pixels = top.load()
    other = Image.new(source.mode, scaled_size1)
    other_pixels = other.load()
    for row in range(dim[1]):
        for col in range(dim[0]):
            pixel = source.getpixel((col, row))
            row_int = math.floor(row / 2)
            if row % 2:
                top_pixels[col, row_int] = pixel
            else:
                other_pixels[col, row_int] = pixel


    top_final = top.resize(scaled_size2, Image.NEAREST) # Downsize to maintain aspect ratio
    other_final = other.resize(scaled_size2, Image.NEAREST) # Downsize to maintain aspect ratio
    top_final.save(output_format_str.format(row_names[0]))
    other_final.save(output_format_str.format(row_names[1]))
```

output_format_str should be something like: `"filename-{}.png"` where the `{}` will be replaced with the row name.

Note that it ends up with the image being half of it's original size. If you don't want this you can twiddle the last scaling step

It's not the fastest operation as it goes through pixel by pixel, but I could not see an easy way to extract rows from an image.